# Can't start docker service after updating to 1.12.6-176.1 in OpenSUSE:

Tags: docker, opensuse

I have updated docker in my OpenSUSE 13.2.
After some tests I see that  -H flag in /etc/sysconfig/docker is causing dockerd not to start, but I need it to enable port 2375 or 2376 (as it has been working OK for months). With it, TSL or not TSL, all or any port, docker will not start. I have tried binding to 0.0.0.0, localhost, ...

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2016-10-25 12:48:00 CEST, end at Thu 2017-02-02 23:02:35 CET. --
Feb 02 23:01:35 ezequiel dockerd[22661]: time="2017-02-02T23:01:35.134216922+01:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Feb 02 23:01:35 ezequiel dockerd[22661]: time="2017-02-02T23:01:35.247510727+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Feb 02 23:01:35 ezequiel dockerd[22661]: time="2017-02-02T23:01:35.247659069+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Feb 02 23:01:35 ezequiel dockerd[22661]: time="2017-02-02T23:01:35.247709386+01:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=78d1802 graphdriver=btrfs version=1.12.6
Feb 02 23:01:35 ezequiel dockerd[22661]: time="2017-02-02T23:01:35.267370317+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on 192.168.100.1:2375"
Feb 02 23:02:35 ezequiel docker_service_helper.sh[22662]: Docker is dead
Feb 02 23:02:35 ezequiel systemd[1]: docker.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 02 23:02:35 ezequiel dockerd[22661]: time="2017-02-02T23:02:35.810756005+01:00" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
Feb 02 23:02:35 ezequiel systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Feb 02 23:02:35 ezequiel systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
```

If I remove it, docker starts, but I can't access it from outside the host (I used to use TSL through port 2376)

I have tried dockerd directly and it binds to tcp port:

```
# /usr/bin/dockerd --containerd /run/containerd/containerd.sock --add-runtime oci=/usr/bin/docker-runc --label provider=generic -g /optLVM/varLibDocker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
WARN[0000] [!] DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting -tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING [!] 
INFO[0000] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver "btrfs" 
INFO[0000] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds 
WARN[0000] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit. 
WARN[0000] Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit. 
WARN[0000] mountpoint for pids not found                
INFO[0000] Loading containers: start.                   
.................INFO[0000] Firewalld running: false                     
INFO[0000] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address 

INFO[0000] Loading containers: done.                    
INFO[0000] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[0000] Docker daemon                                 commit=78d1802 graphdriver=btrfs version=1.12.6
INFO[0000] API listen on 127.0.0.1:2375
```

So it seems something has changed in the configuration.

My old version was:
docker-1.12.1-152.3.x86_64

And new one:
docker-1.12.6-176.1.x86_64

Thanks for any help... I do need TCP, with or without TSL, to access docker remotely.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same Problem after updating.
From 1.12.1 to 1.12.6 they changed somthing with the "fd://". For me it did not work anymore. I'm using tcp with tls.

In my config file (/etc/docker/daemon.json)

```
{
  "tls"      : true,
  "tlsverify": true,
  "tlscacert": "/etc/docker/ca.pem",
  "tlscert"  : "/etc/docker/server/server-cert.pem",
  "tlskey"   : "/etc/docker/server/server-key.pem",
  "hosts"    : ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://10.10.1.1:2376"]
}
```

I am adding the "host": unix:///var/run/docker.sock

I think the local communication is handled via the unix socket and remote connection runs over tcp.

[You can find the Infos here ...](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#bind-docker-to-another-hostport-or-a-unix-socket)